# Error: unexpected type, required: variable and found: value

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read in a string using a for loop but its giving me an error. Just checking if current character is "a":

[image]

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons. Also, don't post pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `==` instead of `=`.

In Java, we can compare two characters either by using the equals `==` operator or the `equals()` method of the `Character` class.

In your case:

```
if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'a') {
    ...
}
```